# Perforce: Finding branches with given source

Tags: perforce

Given a path to a directory, How can I find all the branches in perforce that use the path as a branch source (or destination)?

Comment: When you say all the "branches", do you mean branch specs?

Answer (score 2):

I think `p4 integrated` will give you that information.